# Is referring to a World War II military operation by it's name, obscure?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question about Operation Neptune, specifically around any naval engagements that might have taken place during the landings.

I mentioned Operation Neptune in the title, an admin changed the title to remove Operation Neptune and added Normandy Landings in it's place. I asked why and was told referring to a military operation by it's name is *obscure*.

Keep in mind this wasn't some small 5 man sabotage operation that no one would have ever heard of, it was the biggest seaborne invasion in history.

Would a question about Operation Barbarossa, be changed to *When Germany invaded the Soviet Union*?

**On an Exchange dedicated to History, is referring to a military operation by it's name, obscure**?

Also, the admin that made the change supplied an excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

In general we prefer to see question titles contain the name by which most folks know the thing you are asking about. This helps other people who may be searching on that or a similar question. (Which further helps our traffic here.) If you want to get more specific or detailed, the text of your question is the perfect place for that.

Now it could be that the editor in question had an unusual hole in their knowledge, and thus made their decision in error. It happens. However, given that I'm a mod here and actually had to lookup "Operation Neptune" myself, I think in this case the editor did the right thing.

Note that Wikipedia made this same decision. Search on [Operation Neptune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Operation_Neptune) and you'll find the following at the top of the page:

> The main article for this category is [Invasion of Normandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Normandy).

Comment: I really thought I had made the right call by being as specific as possible. I posted a different question which was admittedly quite ambiguous, which after many many comments, was down voted to oblivion. And now this question is so precise it's _obscure_. This Exchange sure is tough! ha!